# Identify pieces for this Griffin

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, design, part-database

I'd like to make just the top part of [this griffin](https://ideas.lego.com/projects/66275c54-8247-4d8e-b202-e4f186aabee8)
Can you help me identify the eye, ears, beak and that weird curvy white part on top? I think I can find the rest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The builder used *[Set #70124 - Chima Eagle Legend Beast](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=123229#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)* as a template.

To see the online instructions for this set watch this *[**HERE**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LsJ5_PH_5dQ)*. The bird's head construction is on page 14 at 53 seconds in.

For a list and description of all parts used look *[**HERE**](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=70124-1)*.

For further inspiration, check out creator *Markus Buhler*'s alternate Griffen build plus his tutorial *[**HERE**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQZ9N1onU6c)*.

[image]